# Chrome Dev Tools Device Configuration

Tags: android, mobile, display

Hi need to know the proper values to configure the following devices in chrome dev tools.

I cannot find device pixel ratio value on the phones screen specification.

Can anyone share the values for this models:

**
Samsung galaxy S10

Samsung galaxy S10 +

Samsung galaxy S20

Samsung galaxy S10 +

Iphone 11

Iphone 11 PRO
**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find some details here: https://viewportsizer.com/devices/

Samsung Galaxy S10:   360, 740, 4
Samsung Galaxy S10+:  360, 740, 4
Samsung Galaxy S20: 360, 800, 4
Samsung Galaxy S20+: 384, 854, 4
iPhone 11: 414, 896, 2
iPhone 11 Pro: 375, 812, 3